# Kiosk Mode on Android Device

Tags: android, tablet, kiosk-mode, android-task

I’m a developer developing access control application for an Android Facial recognition device.

The application I’m developing should be always running. I’ve tried pinning the app and running the app on 3rd party applicstion such as SureLock but seems like the app will exit after sometime to a page that prompt for password.

Any tips on how to solve this issue?

My suspicion is due to Android system killing off idle app for energy saving.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.